# Rosdep cannot find all required resources

Tags: ros, frame, camera, ros-fuerte, lsd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte. I install lsd_slam and its readme says that

> 

```
Using `live_slam`
If you want to directly use a camera.
rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam /image:=<yourstreamtopic> /camera_info:=<yourcamera_infotopic>
When using ROS camera_info, only the image dimensions and the `K` matrix from the camera info messages will be used - hence the video has to be rectified.
```

I want to use live_slam on ROS. To install camera driver, I find this [blog](http://maztories.blogspot.com.tr/2013/05/ros-gscam-images-from-webcam.html).

Firstly, I run 1.b section not 1.a. Then I tried `rosdep install gscam`, I get below error message.

> ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required
> resources to answer your query Missing
> resource gscam ROS path
> [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros ROS path
> [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share ROS path
> [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks ROS path
> [3]=/home/user/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/

Conetnt of bashrc file is below :

> source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
> export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/fuerte_workspace/
> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH+=:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/
> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH+=:~/fuerte_workspace/gscam/

How can I handle this error? Or, how can I get frame from webcam using ubuntu, ROS, fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212453/rosdep-cannot-find-all-required-resources/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install gscam?

rosdep does NOT install gscam, but dependencies for gscam.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-06-29**:
I install gscam using svn. It locates under fuerte_workspace.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-06-29**:
Something with your paths seems to be wrong. You list the gscam export, but the error provided by rosdep does not contain that path. Maybe you forgot to source something.